# TCL Blowfish behavior

Tags: zip, tcl, blowfish, file-locking

I made a small script that zips a file and then encrypts that file:

```
#-- cut from proc --
set outfile [open $out wb]
set ind [string last \/ $in]
set in [string range $in [expr $ind + 1] end]
zipfile::mkzip::mkzip $in.zip $in
set infile [open $in.zip rb]
if {[catch {blowfish::blowfish -mode $mode -key $key -iv $iv -out $outfile -in $infile} msg]} {
     tk_messageBox -message "Error message: $msg"
     continue
}
close $infile; close $outfile
#-- end of cut --
```

To decipher and unzip:

```
#-- cut from proc --
set outfile [open $out.zip wb]
set infile [open $in rb]
if {[catch {blowfish::blowfish -dir decrypt -mode $mode -key $key -iv $iv -out $outfile -in $infile} msg]} {
     tk_messageBox -message "Error message: $msg"
     close $outfile
     continue
}
close $infile; close $outfile
if {[zipfile::decode::iszip $out.zip] < 1} {
     tk_messageBox -message "bad zip file"
     file delete -force $out.zip
     return
}
zipfile::decode::unzipfile $out.zip $final
file delete -force $out.zip
#-- end of cut --
```

Now, all works fine, *except* if the deciphered zip file is bad, meaning that we've used a bad password or mode. I would've thought that `catch {blowfish` line would get me an error, but apparently blowfish doesn't care, and will just blow garbage into the output file with the .zip extension. In any case, in the case of the bad zip file, the script is not releasing the zip file, and will give me a permission error when trying to delete it. If the zip file is a good file, it will happily unzip and be deleted. I would presume that blowfish has the file locked but won't give an error or let it go. Any help nailing down what I'm doing wrong would be appreciated.

Update: Run the same script on a Linux os at home, and it works. At work on Win10 was the bad behavior, I should've noted that initially.

Comment: Taking a look at the [source](https://core.tcl-lang.org/tcllib/file?name=modules/blowfish/blowfish.tcl&ci=tip), it looks like it neither opens nor closes anything (that's the caller's job, i.e., your code should do it). Problem's probably in the zipfile package.

Comment: And the reason it works on Linux is that you can (usually) delete open files there, unlike on Windows. Different filesystem semantics.

Comment: zipfile is indeed the culprit here, as soon as zipfile touches a bad zip file, I can't get it to release it. in the zipfile source, decode::unzipfile opens, unzips, and closes. I tried testing the zip file before calling unzipfile with decode::iszip and it correctly points out that the zipfile is bad, but it won't release it, either. I tried a decode::close after testing, but it doesn't think there's anything open. Very frustrating.

Answer (score 1):

I've found the <s>problem</s> bug. It's in [`zipfile::decode::LocateEnd`](https://core.tcl-lang.org/tcllib/file?name=modules/zip/decode.tcl&ci=tip&ln=655,737) (called by `iszip` and others), which doesn't close the open file handle to the zip file if it throws an error. I'm not *quite* what all of the conditions are under which it throws an error, but one is definitely when the ZIP index can't be found. Which would be OK… except that the handle's open and *on Windows* that means that the file can't be deleted (because having a file open locks its directory entry; Unixes don't typically work that way).

It's definitely a [bug](https://core.tcl-lang.org/tcllib/tktview/8e5a7e4a420a9e5cf69fa29407ac218c9a6abbf0).

Fortunately it's using a normal Tcl channel, not some kind of complicated C thing, so we can work around it.

```
# Assume you have Tcl 8.5
proc safeIsZip {filename} {
    set channels [file channels]; # Hope this is short!
    catch {
        zipfile::decode::iszip $filename
    } result options
    foreach ch [file channels] {
        if {$ch ni $channels} {
            close $ch
        }
    }
    return -options $options $result
}
```

In Tcl 8.6, you can do it a bit nicer:

```
proc safeIsZip {filename} {
    set channels [file channels]; # Hope this is short!
    try {
        return [zipfile::decode::iszip $filename]
    } finally {
        foreach ch [file channels] {
            if {$ch ni $channels} {
                chan close $ch
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's extremely helpful, thank you very much for taking the time to find that.

Comment: It helped a lot that I knew the sort of thing that I was looking for (a failure to pair up `open` and `close`) and that I could see that there was no calls to them in either `blowfish` or the `iszip` implementation itself (which is a very thin wrapper).

Comment: I can also report that the maintainer of Tcllib has now been made aware of the fault; it should be fixed pretty soon (and a release is due anyway Real Soon). My _preferred_ fix (`try`/`finally` in `LocateEnd`, possibly with a refactor) wouldn't help here, as Tcllib supports older Tcl versions than I do.

Comment: I still had a problem, as the ```set channels [file channels]``` thing didn't work for some reason, but by using ```[chan names]``` instead I was able to make it work that way.

Comment: Weird; `file channels` has been around longer. Still, it doesn't matter too much if you've got it working for now (and the bug should be fixed soon).